# How to select just field from DB

Tags: database

I have
node type= **activation**
with fields = **active_date, status**

Now i want to select from node type **"activation"**, where is **active_date** (less as) **today** and **status=active** and get nid's.

Comment: What's "active_date"?

Comment: Did you add a custom field in activation type content type?

Comment: Yes, its custom field with date

Comment: Where are you trying to select it?

Comment: Can you show us what code you are using?